# Schema in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php

```
# config/doctrine/schema.yml
Category:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

Project:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
    title:         { type: string(255) }
    description:  { type: string(4000), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Category: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Projects }
```

Here,

If we change

local: category_id 'to' foreign_key: category_id

and

foreign: id 'to' references: id

Then will it make greater sense or the Original One does?

I'm mean creators of Symfony are really experienced [Jonathan Wage and Fabien Potencier] so they must be following some DB Design that I maynot know .

Just curious to know If someone knows why it is, the Way it is in Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a pity that the documentation is extensive and at the same time sparse in very fundamental sections, such as the database schema.

AFAIK, we have the following structure for a given relation:

```
"Alias":        #Name of the set of records in the other table, referenced from this table
  foreignAlias:   #Name of the set of records in this table, referenced from the other table
  type:           #multiplicity of the records in the other table; can be "one" or "many"
  foreignType:    #multiplicity of the records in this table; can be "one" or "many"
  local:          #field of this table that references records of the other table
                  #for a many to many relation, field of the middle table that references records of this table
  class:          #class of the other table; identifies referenced records
  foreign:        #field of the other table; identifies referenced records
                  #for a many to many relation, field of the middle table that references records of the other table
  refClass:       #for a many to many relation, class of the middle table
  onDelete:       #database level referential integrity, only on the table that owns the foreign key
  onUpdate:       #database level referential integrity, only on the table that owns the foreign key
  cascade:        #application level cascade
  foreignKeyName: #name of the constraint for the foreign key
```

IMO, could be much simpler and more intuitive.